# Can a human land on Mercury?

Tags: mercury

Can a human in a normal astronaut suit designed for the moon, land on Mercury and walk on it's surface. If not what would happen to him/her?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the https://space.stackexchange.com/ site.

Answer (score 2):

No sir/madam. An astronaut or a cosmonaut cannot walk on Mercury's surface. The reason is plainly simple. During daytime, its temperature surges up to 430 degree C making it 2nd hottest planet after Venus. Whereas, night time temperatures are as low as -180 degree C.

Despite of having ice caps at its polar regions which might seem attractive, its totally not feasible to land there and then mine the frozen ice to make up a base.

For a much more descriptive read, kindly refer this link : [What it would be to live on Mercury](http://www.space.com/28356-how-to-live-on-mercury.html)

Comment: If you consider Mercury's rotation period around the sun vs. the rotation period of itself, there is indeed a zone where humans can live in double-knit suits.

Comment: Why can't you land in the polar regions? It's more delta v to inject into a polar orbit but nothing compared to the transfer to get there.